# Is it possible to use predefined variables in user-defined variables:

Tags: variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wanted to define variable for docker image name using branch name as tag, as defined in documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html :

```
variables:
 CONTAINER_NAME: myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
 CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME: myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME
```

however, when I output CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME, I get:

> myrepo:5000/myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

It means, that my own variables are expanded, but the predefined ones not, although they are available in script execution time, because when I `echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, I get branch name, as expected.

Is it possible to use predefined variables as a part of my defined variables, or the documentation is misleading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question: No, the way you "cascade" (nest) one substitution into another...

...but there are clean workarounds (should I say solutions)

Consider the following:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: ubuntu

variables:
  # Original
  CONTAINER_NAME: myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME: myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME
  #
  # Added to look for a workaround
  CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX: 'myimage:'
  CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX: myrepo:5000/
  CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME_V2: $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX$CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  #
  # Suggested workaround
  MY_IMAGE: myimage
  MY_REPO: myrepo:5000
  SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_NAME: $MY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME: $MY_REPO/$MY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

test:
  script:
  # Just the relevant variables:
  - echo '*** Just the variables:'
  - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  - echo $CONTAINER_NAME
  - echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
  - echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME_V2
  # Combinations of text and variables
  - echo '*** Combinations of text and variables:'
  - echo myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME
  - echo 'myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME'
  - echo "myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME"
  - echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX$CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  # Suggested workarounds:
  - echo '*** Suggested workarounds:'
  - echo $SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_NAME
  - echo $SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
```

Produces this output:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.0 (0118d89)
  on docker-auto-scale (e11ae361)
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu ...
Using docker image sha256:a9db1f09b71a10fe42d8ac456c24d961dccd06968e72d2f476df20a12cb41f3d for predefined container...
Pulling docker image ubuntu ...
Using docker image ubuntu ID=sha256:ebcd9d4fca80e9e8afc525d8a38e7c56825dfb4a220ed77156f9fb13b14d4ab7 for build container...
Running on runner-e11ae361-project-3324498-concurrent-0 via runner-e11ae361-machine-1495045360-f78e2b0f-digital-ocean-2gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/elingerojo/CI-sandbox'...
Checking out 09b782b9 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo '*** Just the variables:'
*** Just the variables:
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
master
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
myimage:master
$ echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
$ echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME_V2
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
$ echo '*** Combinations of text and variables:'
*** Combinations of text and variables:
$ echo myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
$ echo 'myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME'
myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME
$ echo "myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME"
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
$ echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX$CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
$ echo '*** Suggested workarounds:'
*** Suggested workarounds:
$ echo $SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_NAME
myimage:master
$ echo $SUGGESTED_CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
Job succeeded
```

There are 5 correct outputs. Choose one that fit your style :)

---

Side Note:

The "original" problem consists on assigning more than one substitution text **level** per symbol (symbol is the left side of an assignment, ex `CONTAINER_NAME`). Means, you can not have "nested" substitutions like in `CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME` that "depends" on deeper level (nested) substitution of `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` thru the symbol `CONTAINER_NAME`.

You can use multiple substitution at the same time as long as they are not nested

---

### Option 1

```
image: ubuntu

variables:
  # Just two lines, all info at top of the script
  CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX: myimage
  CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX: myrepo:5000
  # Two auxiliary vars
  CONTAINER_NAME: $CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME: $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX/$CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

test:
  script:
  - echo $CONTAINER_NAME
  - echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
```

Output:

```
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
myimage:master
$ echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
```

### Option 2

```
image: ubuntu

variables:
  CONTAINER_NAME: myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX: myrepo:5000

test:
  script:
  # As bash value with double quotes
  # (could be assigned to an environment variable)
  - echo "myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME"
  # Or used directly in any command without quotes
  - echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX/$CONTAINER_NAME
```

Output:

```
$ echo "myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME"
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
$ echo $CONTAINER_PUSH_PREFIX/$CONTAINER_NAME
myrepo:5000/myimage:master
```

Comment: But what exactly is wrong with the original "cascading"?

Comment: The "variable" substitution does not work like a common variable value assignation.
The substitution happens before running the code. It is like a preparation. The "parser/compiler/interpreter" looks for places to substitute the "variables" without updating the look-for value. For instance, `$CONTAINER_NAME` is nor updated until the end of all substitutions. So it will have the literal value `myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` during the substitution phase. Later, at "run time" the value assignation makes `CONTAINER_PUSH_NAME` get the `myrepo:5000/myimage:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` literal value

Comment: Did you look at the doble quoted case? It is very interesting because is a special case where substitution happens "twice" and looks a lot like you were trying to do. I mean, the code where says `$ echo "myrepo:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME"` and outputs 
`myrepo:5000/myimage:master`

Comment: I'm not the OP and yes I do understand how double quotes works in bash variables, they are evaluate on run time so you can even assign commands to them instead of command results. But I just don't quite get the original problem, I'll experiment with it later maybe.

Comment: Sorry, I did not look at your username and asume you were the OP, my bad. Added a side note about the 'original' problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's still the workaround for me, because changing the way I tag the image requires me to change in a few places (CONTAINER_NAME, push and pull name), but at least all are at the top of the script. I'm still unhappy in the way it works, but now I understand how it works, I can reasonably plan what is the most maintanable way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Check if [GitLab 13.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/#nested-variable-expansion) (March 2021, 4 years later) can help in your case:

> ### Nested variable expansion
>
> Sometimes you need to define a variable in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and use it in another variable definition.
>
> **We are introducing the new nested variables expansion feature.**
>
> When enabled, GitLab sorts and expands job variables recursively before sending the final output to the runner for job execution.
> This specific sorting allows variables to be sent from GitLab CI/CD to the runner in a sequence that resolves correctly.
>
> Now, you can easily use variables inside other variables in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_10/nested_variables.png -- Nested variable expansion]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#nested-variable-expansion) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26345).